# reading multiple files into dask dataframe

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

I want to read multiple csv files into one single dask dataframe. Due to some reasons some portion of my original data get lost (no clue why?!). I am wondering whats the best method to read them all into dask? I used a for loop though not sure if its correct.

> ```
>  for file in os.listdir(dds_glob):
>     if file.endswith('issued_processed.txt'):
>         ddf = dd.read_fwf(os.path.join(dds_glob,file),
>                           colspecs=cols,
>                           header=None,
>                           dtype=object,
>                           names=names)
> ```

or should I use something like this:

> ```
> dfs = delayed(pd.read_fwf)('/data/input/*issued_processed.txt',
>                            colspecs=cols,
>                            header=None,
>                            dtype=object,
>                            names=names)  
> ddf = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two approaches:

1. provide `dask.dataframe` with a list of files, so using your first snippet it would look like:

```py
file_list = [
    os.path.join(dds_glob,file)
    for file os.listdir(dds_glob) if file.endswith('issued_processed.txt')
]

# other options are skipped for convenience
ddf = dd.read_fwf(file_list)
```

2. construct dataframe from `delayed` objects, which using your second snippet would look like:

```py
# other options are skipped, but can be included after the `file`
dfs = [delayed(pd.read_fwf)(file) for file in file_list] 
ddf = dd.from_delayed(dfs)
```

The first approach is something that will solve about 82% of the use-cases, but for the other cases you might need to try the second approach or something more involved.

Comment: I like "other use cases" :)

Comment: Thanks, both works smoothly, though I have some other issues for the rest of the computation